# WaveSurf.js not showing on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

i'm trying to use wavesurfer.js but it doesn't work on Chrome. I've tried the same program in firefox and works perfectly.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" 
    integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" 
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="audio-container" style = "box-shadow: 0 4px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
        <div class="track-name" style="position: absolute;color: white;"> Antidote</div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
        <div class="waveform" style="background-color: #222; width: 100%; height: 130px;"></div>
        <div class = "buttons">
            <span class=" play-btn btn">
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i> 
            <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>    
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '.waveform',
            waveColor: '#eee',
            progressColor: 'red',
            barWidth: 2
        });

        wavesurfer.load('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0572/6499/6512/files/Rosewood_140_bpm_D_m.wav?v=1651737669');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console gives me this warning:
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
Can someone explain to me why it's not working? Other sites using wavesurfer display perfectly even on chrome, but mine seems to not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok guys solved. But now i have a new problem... it seems that it doesn't work on mobile. What can be the problem? Other sites using WaveSurfer seems works

Comment: +1 I am experiencing this also however not sure what has changed recently from the providers code as I haven't changed mine

Comment: Hello, @Andrea, how do you solved the first problem you have with the failed to load source map?